# Null Exception declaring gridview in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Part of this issue is stemming from embedding a GridView in a FormView and running SQL on the GridView controls.

GirdView Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBFProd" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BFProdID" DataSourceID="BFProdSQL" OnRowCommand="gvBFProd_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Save"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" CommandName="FooterInsert" Text="Insert"  />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
...
```

CodeBehind

```
private GridView gvBFProd;
    protected void gvBFProd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        gvBFProd = FormView1.Row.FindControl("gvBFProd") as GridView;

        if (e.CommandName == "FooterInsert" && Page.IsValid)
        {
            // Reference GridView Controls
            TextBox txtBFID = (TextBox)FormView1.Row.FindControl("txtBFID");
            DropDownList ddlSeries =
                (DropDownList)gvBFProd.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlFooterSeries");
            TextBox txtACMWelders =
                (TextBox)gvBFProd.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFooterACMWelders");
....                

// Update InsertParameters
            BFProdSQL.InsertParameters.Clear();

            BFProdSQL.InsertParameters.Add("BFID", txtBFID.Text);
            BFProdSQL.InsertParameters.Add("SeriesID", ddlSeries.SelectedValue);
            BFProdSQL.InsertParameters.Add("NumACMWelders", txtACMWelders.Text);
...         


// Insert new record
            BFProdSQL.Insert();
        }
    }
```

The initial `private GridView gvBFProd;` was necessary to give context to the GridView control references due to being embedded in the FormView. However, either something isn't passing correctly or there's something more I need to do with the `private GridView gvBFProd;` line. I'm thinking the latter as once the project is built, I get the green squiggly under gvBFProd stating the field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null. And of course when I click on the Insert LinkButton, I get an unhandled Null Exception error that breaks at the `(DropdownList)gvBFProd.FooterRow....` line.

Do I need to build get/set funtions for gvBFProd or is there a different way of passing the GridView?

Comment: why are you declaring "private GridView gvBFProd;"??

Comment: gvBFProd will be already declared in designer file

Comment: Perhaps declaring it in your file is hiding the gvBFPROD from the code behind. And since you never initialize it, you can an ER when you try to access its properties. Delete that declaration and see if it works.

Comment: When I delete the "private GridView gvBFProd;" then I get red squigglies under all the Control declaration that says that gvBFProd does not exist in this context. it isn't an issue if I move the GridView outside of the <asp:FormView></asp:FormView> block, but when the GridView is nested inside the FormView, I get the context errors. Hence the gvBFProd declaration. If there's a better solution to fix the context errors, I'm all for that as well.

Comment: I'm beginning to think something isn't passing right. I took out the "private GridView gvBFProd;" line and moved my GridViews outside of the context of the FormView. Now when clicking the Insert button, I get a Null Reference Exception error on my first InsertParameters.Add() line stating that Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. Isn't that what I did in the //Reference GridView Controls section above the code for updating the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what was causing the original Null Exception errors. I was missing the definition of gvBFProd in the codebehind.

Specifically:

```
private GridView gvBFProd;
    protected void gvBFProd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        gvBFProd = FormView1.Row.FindControl("gvBFProd") as GridView;
....
```

Now I'm getting a different Null Reference Exception on my dropdown lists, but that's a different issue.